# Match sections of a List, and Replace if both exist

Tags: c#, list, replace, match

I've got dates from separate countries within a single `List<>`.  I'm trying to get two records that contain the same characters before the second comma, and replace BOTH of those items with a new one.

Example:

From This:

```
18/04/2014,Good Friday,England and Wales
18/04/2014,Good Friday,Scotland
```

Into this:

```
18/04/2014,Good Friday,"England, Wales and Scotland"
```

Please note there may be multiple scenarios within the list like the above example. I've managed to get everything before the second Comma with:

`splitSubstring = line.Remove(line.LastIndexOf(','));`

I've tried the below, but it's clearly flawed since it won't delete both the records even if it does find a match:

```
foreach (var line in orderedLines)
{
    if (splitSubstring == line.Remove(line.LastIndexOf(',')))
        {
        //Replace if previous is match here
        }
    splitSubstring = line.Remove(line.LastIndexOf(','));
    File.AppendAllText(correctFile, line);
}
```

Comment: Side notes: get familiar with "C# LINQ set operations" (search for it) and for future posts avoid adding text like "thank you" and "searched alot" - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=remove+fluff. If you want to demonstrate your effort - show code you've tried (one in this post has nothing to do with the question).

Comment: Do you really want `18/04/2014,Good Friday,England, Wales and Scotland` or is `18/04/2014,Good Friday,"England, Wales and Scotland"` better (as it is valid CSV)?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the quotation marks, will update

Comment: @Enigmativity you are indeed right - somehow I read as OP has two lists... This could be just `.GroupBy` but parsing/merging code is pain, especially since regular `String.Join` would not work...

Comment: @Alz_dev - Could your source file also already contain quotation marks?

Comment: @Alz_dev - You need to use [FileHelpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filehelpers?sort=votes&pageSize=50&mixed=1) for this.

Comment: @Alz_dev you need to make an attempt.  The code you've posted is not even close to an attempt.  StackOverflow isn't an outsourcing service.

Comment: I don't expect someone else to complete this. I have been looking for a solution for quite some time, simple pointers would suffice. The code I've provided is merely an example of something I've tried.
@Enigmativity the source code does not have quotation marks. I'm moving the strings into a Class where I think LINQ could be the answer. I'll also look through FileHelpers, thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @Alz_dev - Your source has `18/04/2014,Good Friday,England and Wales` - so what happens if the source contains an item with 3 or more locations already? What does that look like?

Comment: @Enigmativity - `26-12-2012,Boxing Day,england-and-wales`

`26-12-2012,Boxing Day,scotland`

Comment: @Alz_dev - The format appears to be changing.

Comment: Sorry, I pulled that from the wrong file.
`26/12/2012,Boxing Day,England and Wales`

`26/12/2012,Boxing Day,Scotland`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using LINQ to pull apart the List and .Add() them into another based on an if statement. LINQ made it nice and simple.

`//Using LINQ to seperate the two locations from the list.
var seperateScotland = from s in toBeInsertedList
where s.HolidayLocation == scotlandName
select s;`

`var seperateEngland = from e in toBeInsertedList
where e.HolidayLocation == engAndWales
select e;`

Thanks for pointing me to LINQ

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest parsing it into a structure you can work with e.g.

```
public class HolidayInfo
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string[] Countries { get; set; }
};
```

And then

```
string[] lines = new string[]
{
    "18/04/2014,Good Friday,England and Wales",
    "18/04/2014,Good Friday,Scotland"
};

// splits the lines into an array of strings
IEnumerable<string[]> parsed = lines.Select(l => l.Split(','));
// copy the parsed lines into a data structure you can write code against
IEnumerable<HolidayInfo> info = parsed
    .Select(l => new HolidayInfo
    {
        Date = DateTime.Parse(l[0]),
        Name = l[1],
        Countries = l[2].Split(new[] {",", " and " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    });
```

...etc.  And once you have it in a helpful data structure you can begin to develop the required logic.  The above code is just an example, the approach is what you should focus on.

Comment: This looks more elegant than what I've done - I'll note this down for future, thanks

Comment: @Alz_dev on Stack Overflow, rather than just commenting thanks, a better expression of gratitude is to up vote the answer and / or mark as the answer to give the person some credit.